# Holding a bank account in the US, without citizenship, while no longer living there

Tags: united-states, banking, bank-account, working-abroad

I travelled to the US for a 3 month project and was paid into this account. I have since left and still have money in the account and still in good contact with the people whose address I stayed at.

Is there any problem with this? It could foreseeably be used to make some digital online purchases. I was not required to have a SSN when creating the account. I applied for one 4 months ago but have not received it since. 
Bonus question: I was told I would have to file a tax return, but did not receive my SSN, what happens in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You have to have a SSN if you work in the US, and you have to file a tax return and pay taxes on your earnings. Not doing so may cause troubles to you on your next visit to the US, and if the US has a treaty with your country, they can come after you back at home. Whether they are going to or not is a different question.